# org.json.JSONException: Value failure_post of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, android-volley, json

I want to send data to server with `volly library` When I send data to server with `volley library` I get the following Error:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value failure_post of type 
                     java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

This is my java code:

```
public void insertClick(View view)
{
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    HashMap<String, JSONObject> jsonParams = new HashMap<String, JSONObject>();

    JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
    try
    {
        params.put("title","BOOK");
        params.put("intro","hellothere");
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {

        Log.i(LABLE, "erorr is : "+ e.getMessage().toString());
    }

    try {

        JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,

        new JSONObject(jsonParams),
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , " insert ok ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //   Handle Error

                Log.i(LABLE, "erorr is : "+ error.getMessage().toString());

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , " insert failed ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

                return headers;
            }
        };
        queue.add(postRequest);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this , "erorr in Json Object Request ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: where is the error??

Comment: new JSONObject(jsonParams) this only work with MAP<String, String>

Comment: Instead of `new JSONObject(jsonParams),`, IMO, you should use `params` only or `new JSONObject(params),`

Answer (score 0):

Create a `JsonArray`

add jsonObjects to that array

and then send a complete `JsonObject` create from `JsonArray` to `JsonObjectRequest`

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `params` instead of `jsonParams` in your `JsonObjectRequest` ie,

**Replace this**

```
JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,new JSONObject(jsonParams),...
```

**With**

```
JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,params,...
```

Or retrieve from map after putting in it as follows

```
jsonParams.get("key")
```